# Can we un-synonymize the 'festivals' tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

Currently, the [festivals](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/festivals) tag has three synonyms, [holi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holi), [diwali](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diwali), and [ganesh-chaturthi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ganesh-chaturthi). It seems to me that these should be un-synonymized because each of the traditions has its own history and customs and rituals associated with it. According to  [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/1278220) Meta post, the only way to have this done is to ask a mod to do so.

(I'm not completely sure that this is the right to do, but it seems like a decent idea in my opinion.)